# How can I pass arguments to supervisor from command line

Tags: elixir

I want to pass arguments to a supervisor while I start an application like

```
mix run project.exs arg1 arg2
```

Now I don't know how to start an application with a script(exs) file which will start my supervisor (with those arguments)

I know about

```
escript: [main_module: App]
```

in mix.exs, provide def main(args): and then:

```
mix escript.build
./app
```

but it doesn't help me

I am totally new to elixir, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically arguments are passed to an application by means of environment variables[1].

You can then start your application by setting them in the commandline as such:

```
ARG1=value ARG2=value mix run project.exs
```

In your code you can then fetch them by means of

```
iex> System.get_env("ARG1")
value
```

[1] https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#get_env/2

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.argv()

example:

```
 def fun(n) do
      --code
     end

    n= System.argv()
```