# How to pass command line arguements to mix run --no-halt

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, erlang-supervisor, elixir-iex

So I have an Application module which follows this layout:

```
defmodule Project.Application do


  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      randomchild1,
      randomchild2,
      {Project.runapp, "argument" }
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_all, name: Project.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Now when i run this i use `mix run --no-halt` and it runs perfectly.

I want to replace the "argument" with a value that I pass in the command line? I cannot figure out how do I add arguments to `mix run --no-halt`.

All I want to do is pass a value to the start method and use it to define the child process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734459/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-supervisor-from-command-line/57741353#57741353

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass arguments to supervisor from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734459/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-supervisor-from-command-line)

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer neither of the answers you linked works with `--no-halt`.

Answer (score 6):

`mix` [voluntarily resets](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.1/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/run.ex#L121) [`System.argv/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#argv/1). The `--no-halt` option is an ad-hoc way of running applications; normally we assemble releases with `mix release` and start them normally with `ebin/my_app start`.

While you still want to resort to `mix run --no-halt`, create the empty file (`mix` will attempt to execute it upon start,) and call `mix` like

```
mix run --no-halt -- "empty.exs" 42
```

Now inside your `Application.start/2` you can get arguments with `System.argv/0`

```
def start(_type, args) do
  IO.inspect(System.argv())

  ...
```

Check it.

```
mix run --no-halt -- "empty.exs" 42
#⇒ ["422"]
```